# Formatting date in R with fractional seconds and AM/PM indicator

Tags: r

I have a `data.frame` with strings that are similar to  `"7/30/2009 9:18:35.000000 PM"`. The format is somewhat unusual as it has been extracted from a database dump.

I am trying to convert these strings using `as.POSIXct`. From the documentation in `strptime`, I believe that `format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%OS %p"` — `%OS` to capture the fractional seconds and `%p` to capture the time of day:

```
as.POSIXct("7/30/2009 9:18:35.000000 PM", format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%OS %p")
[1] "2009-07-30 09:18:35 EDT"
```

I would expect this to return `"2009-07-30 21:18:35 EDT"` instead.
It looks like either the trailing zeros in the seconds field or the AM/PM indicator are causing issues.

Any ideas?

Here is some example data:

```
v <- c("7/31/2009 7:35:38.000000 AM", "7/30/2009 9:18:35.000000 PM", 
"7/30/2009 9:18:30.000000 PM", "7/30/2009 9:18:40.000000 PM", 
"7/30/2009 9:18:39.000000 PM", "7/30/2009 9:19:29.000000 PM", 
"7/30/2009 9:18:42.000000 PM", "7/30/2009 9:18:45.000000 PM", 
"7/31/2009 7:35:31.000000 AM", "7/31/2009 7:35:30.000000 AM")
```

Comment: You probably need `%I`. `as.POSIXct("7/30/2009 9:18:35.000000 PM", format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%OS %p")`

Comment: yep that worked, I missed that conversion specifier! Can you add your comment as an answer so I can close the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need `%I`

From the document,

> %I - Hours as decimal number (01–12).

and

> %H -Hours as decimal number (00–23).

```
as.POSIXct("7/30/2009 9:18:35.000000 PM", format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%OS %p")
# [1] "2009-07-30 21:18:35 IST"
```

Answer (score 2):

strptime("7/30/2009 9:18:35.00000 PM" , "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"